# Limit superior and inferior, giving an example to show that it is possible to have ($a_n$) $>$ $L$ for infinitely many $n$

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

**Question:** Suppose that ($a_n$) is a sequence such that L = lim sup ($a_n$) is a real number. Then we know that, for any number $M$ $>$ $L$, there are only finitely many integers $n$ for which ($a_n$) $>$ $M$. Show by means of an example that it is possible to have ($a_n$) $>$ $L$ for infinitely
many n.

I don't really understand what the question means, any further explanation would be really appreciated. There is a Proposition in my textbook that I think may be helpful for this question, but I am not sure.

- **Proposition 2.20**

(a) If $L$ = $lim$ $sup$ ($a_n$) then

- for each $ε$ $>$ 0 the inequality ($a_n$) $>$ $L$ + $ε$ holds for only finitely many n and
- For each $ε$ $>$ 0 the inequality ($a_n$) $>$ $L$ - $ε$ holds for infinitely many n

Any help would be really appreciated

Thanks a lot

Comment: HINT: If $a_n=\frac1n$, what is $\limsup_na_n$?

Comment: Would the $lim$ $sup$ ($a_n$) be 0?

Comment: It would indeed.

Comment: Sorry, what is this question asking? I don't quite understand what example I need to show.

Comment: It’s simply asking for a sequence that has infinitely many terms that are larger than the lim sup. It’s asking for this because if you take any number *bigger* than the lim sup, only finitely many terms of the sequence can be larger than that number. In the example that I suggested, if $b>0$, only finitely many of the terms $\frac1n$ are greater than $b$, but *all* of them are greater than the lim sup $0$.